# Changing theoremstyle

Tags: amsmath, amsthm, definition

I wanted to change the way "Definition 1.1" is displayed. Specifically, I want to make the name of the definition (green box in attached image) appear in bold (which I know I could do with \textbf, but I want to know if it can be done with some other way). I also want to make the point (red box) dissappear.

I've tried changing `newtheoremstyle`'s parameters, but nothing was achieved.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\title{Math class}
\author{Pablo García López}
\date{June 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Line integral}

\begin{definition}[Opposite curve]
\label{curvaOpuesta}
Let $\gamma: [a, b] \to \R$ be a curve $\mathcal{C}^1$. Then the opposite curve \textcolor{red}{curva opuesta} se define como $-\gamma: [-b, -a] \to \R, (-\gamma)(t) = \gamma(-t)$
\end{definition}

We can observe that on \ref{curvaOpuesta} we don't need \dots

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The  theorem name does appear in bold, as far as I can see.

Comment: I guess you don't want the period also when there is no “name”. Could you  please tell if my guess is correct?

Comment: @egreg your guess is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 4.3.2 on page 10 of the user guide of the `amsthm` package explains how to achieve your formatting objective.

In the code below, I first define a new theorem style called `definitionBoldNote`, and then issue the directive `\theoremstyle{definitionBoldNote}` before running `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]`.

Note also that I've replaced both instances of `:` with `\colon`, in order to obtain asymmetric spacing around the colon character.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue}

\newtheoremstyle{definitionBoldNote}% % see p. 10 of user manual of amsthm package
{\topsep}%  Space above
{\topsep}%  Space below
{}%     Body font
{}%     Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}%    Punctuation after theorem head -- none
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}% Theorem head spec 


\theoremstyle{definitionBoldNote}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\title{Math class}
\author{Pablo García López}
\date{June 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Line integral}

\begin{definition}[Opposite curve]
\label{curvaOpuesta}
Let $\gamma\colon [a, b] \to \R$ be a curve $\mathcal{C}^1$. Then the opposite curve se define como $-\gamma\colon [-b, -a] \to \R$, $(-\gamma)(t) = \gamma(-t)$.
\end{definition}

We can observe from definition \ref{curvaOpuesta} that we don't need \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `3pt`? It should be either nothing or `\topsep` (the standard value).

Comment: @egreg - Good catch! Not sure at which point I copied in `3pt`. Fixed now.

Comment: @egreg To a global view, it's better to set it to be `\parskip`  if the `\parskip` is set to be stretched value different from the `\lineskip`.

Comment: @M.Logic - The `amsthm` package provides three "theorem styles". The default style is labelled `plain`. The other two -- `definition` and `remark` -- are quite similar *except* for the amount of whitespace padding they insert above and below the theorem-like environment: the `definition` style inserts some whitespace before and after the environment, whereas the `remark` style is set not to insert any vertical whitespace padding. For this to work, the length parameter that determines the amount of padding for the `definition` style mustn't be zero. Hence, using `\parskip` cannot really work.

Comment: There is no fixed setting for theorems, definition and remark. I like to set the same space to them.

Comment: @M.Logic - You are certainly perfectly free to do whatever you want. I, for one, have not said and will never say otherwise.